# How to display cck node fields' values at the search result page?

Tags: search, nodes, entities

I need to display some specific cck fields such as Telephone Number, Address, etc. at the search result page.

As I see the `search-result.tpl.php`, there is no `$node->...` So how can I get the node fields into search result page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**[SORTED]**

wow, that simple :)

**search-result.tpl.php**

```
<?php if ($result['node']->field_name[0]['value']): ?>
  <h4><?php print($result['node']->field_name[0]['value']); ?></h4>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It seems there's risks with this method? —http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

Answer (score 3):

In your theme, you can use [`template_preprocess_search_result()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_search_result/6)

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'node') {
    $node =& $variables['result']['node'];
    //Do something here
  }
}
```

Or, you can also implement [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi/6) in a custom module for `$op = 'search result'`. The result of `hook_nodeapi($node, 'search result')` is available in `$info_split` in the `search-result.tpl.php` template.

Answer (score 1):

We had to create a custom search once. We created a custom module that allowed not only writing a custom query to the database but also choose the kind of amount that gets displayed. We hooked into [`hook_search`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_search/6) with the module. To give you an idea:

```
function yourmodule_search($op = 'search', $keys = NULL) {

switch ($op) {
   //some code, basically a stripped version from what the API shows us
    case 'search':

      $find = do_event_search($keys); //the actual search

      // Load results.
      $results = array();

      foreach ($find as $item) { 

        //iteration and adding certain elements to $resuls needned by Drupal
      }
      return $results;
  }
}
```

The interessting part for you is the retrival of the search results as done by `do_event_search`:

```
//all data comes from a queries to the database
$search_result[] = array ('link' => trim($link),
                    'snippet' => trim_text(i18n_get_lang() == "en" ? $row->description_en : $row->description_de),
                    'head' => trim_text(i18n_get_lang() == "en" ? $row->title_en : $row->title_de),
                    'type' => $type
                );
```

As you can see, `snippet` holds the text that should be displayed on the search pages and we select a certain `$row` from a custom database. The API example shows all fields that are needed for displaying the results properly.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds), it allows you to override the node indexing as well as the display of the search results

Answer (score 0):

you could use the template_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) function (copy it from the search module and place it in your theme's template.php file) - 
and use the $variables variable (var_dump it) to retrieve your node info and print it